# Discrepancy in output volume calculation for same rasters in QGIS and Rasterio

Tags: qgis, python, rasterio, volume

I have been comparing my volume calculation results on the same rasters with QGIS Raster Surface Volume tool and the following python script:

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np

filename = 'D:/raster.tif'

with rasterio.open(filename) as src:
    array = src.read()
    meta = src.meta
    area = meta['transform'][0] ** 2 # Pixel size in X
volumes = array * area
volumes = np.float64(volumes)
total_volume = volumes.sum()

print(total_volume)
```

So for example, my first raster input is that of a whole area.

QGIS resulting volume is `-18632.99997425079`
and Rasterio's resulting volume is `-18632.999974250793`

which is fantastic!! They're both the same - yippee!!

[image: Original Raster of whole area]

However, not so yippee when I want the volume of a subsection of the raster. To do this I extracted by mask an area of the original raster and called it subsection.tif and ran it through the volume calculation algorithms.

This time the volume results were as follows:

QGIS - `-13799.01000881195`

Rasterio - `-4.995344848653604e+41`

**Subsection of Raster**

[image: Subsection of Raster]

**Subsection of raster in relation to the original**
[image: Subsection of raster in relation to the original]

BIG DIFFERENCE!

What has happened to cause such a discrepancy with the subsection when the original raster's results were so exact?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe  rasterio thinks the nodata values are valid data.  Maybe apply a nodata mask before calculating the volumns?  https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/masks.html?highlight=NoData#  This would hold true if there were no nodata values in the original file (QGIS and rasterio return the same values) and nodata values in the clipped file.  Maybe post some pictures of your two rasters?

Comment: @GBG sadly even with the array variable code changed to ```array = src.read(1, masked=True)``` I still get ```-4.995344848653604e+41``` as the answer. I will post pictures of my rasters in my original question now

Comment: The x, y, and z values of the subset use the same unit of measure?

Comment: @GBG Yeah it should be an exact replica

Comment: Here is a 100m wide x 100m long x 50 m high pyramid.  The sum of the pixels in this pyramid are 171700.  What happens when you run your code against these data. https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7ha94jlrls6id8/pyramid2.tfw?dl=0